# Interactive Grid - adding filter for more than one value

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I am setting a filter for an IG for `Field1 equals 'My Value1'`. It works fine but now when I try to add another value to the filter I use `Field1 IN 'My Value1', 'Test'`, whatever was displayed with one filter disappears. I also tried `Field1 IN 'My Value1,Test'` but nothing appears. I used similar filter in other grids and it worked. I can't find any way to debug it to see what is going on. Anyone can tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to see in the hint here:

[image: screenshot of filter dialog]

...but the separator to use is a semi-colon ";" e.g.

```
My Value1;Test
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Hmmm, mine does not have any hint, just a blank text box